# The provided plugin com.bnorm.power.PowerAssertComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I use `com.bnorm.power.kotlin-power-assert` gradle plugin, with Kotlin 1.4 IR compiler.

When I'm trying to run debug in Intellij IDEA it fails with an exception:

```
Kotlin: kotlinc-jvm 1.4.10 (JRE 11.0.9.1+1-LTS)
Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: The provided plugin com.bnorm.power.PowerAssertComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerExtensionsFromPlugins$cli(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:571)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.registerExtensionsFromPlugins(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:129)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:109)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:421)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:220)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:151)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1474)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.bnorm.power.PowerAssertComponentRegistrar does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void registerProjectComponents(com.intellij.mock.MockProject, org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.CompilerConfiguration)' of interface org.jetbrains.kotlin.compiler.plugin.ComponentRegistrar.
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerExtensionsFromPlugins$cli(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:563)
    ... 28 more
```

In the same time I can run gradle with `--debug-jvm` flag and attach IDEA to process.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Make sure Kotlin IDE plugin version exactly matches the version with which the `kotlin-power-assert` compiler plugin is compatible. Kotlin compiler does not have a stable API, so AbstractMethodErrors are somewhat expected with third-party plugins.

If all versions match, please create an issue at http://kotl.in/issue with a sample project and steps to reproduce. Thank you.